# azure api-management case-when expression evaluated not as expected

Tags: azure-api-management

can't understand the reason why expression for the second `when` is evaluated to `true` when i'm expecting `false`

here what I see in response (formatted message to be able to compare 2 thumbprints)

```
403: invalid client certificate 
`A5958B8D39A945764110E210A19952FA5C9CAC9A` != 
`‎A5958B8D39A945764110E210A19952FA5C9CAC9A`
```

policy part that is responsible for this validation looks like this:

```xml
    <inbound>
        <base />

        <set-variable name="clientCert" value="{{Client-Thumbprint}}" />
        <set-variable name="testCert" value="{{Test-Thumbprint}}" />

        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null || !context.Request.Certificate.Verify())">
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="403" reason="certificate is missing or not valid" />
                </return-response>
            </when>
            <when condition='@(
                    (string)context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint.ToUpper() != ((string)context.Variables["clientCert"]).ToUpper() && 
                    (string)context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint.ToUpper() != ((string)context.Variables["testCert"]).ToUpper()
                )'>
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="403" reason='@( string.Format("invalid client certificate `{0}` != `{1}`",
                            (string)context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint.ToUpper(),
                            ((string)context.Variables["clientCert"]).ToUpper() 
                        )' />
                </return-response>
            </when>
        </choose>
        ...
    </inbound>
```

i'm sure that thumbprint in request equal to value of `clientCert` variable.

i'm not asking how to rework this code.

my question: what's wrong with second `when` expression - why it's evaluated to `true` when it should be `false`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow to achieve the above requirement ;

> my question: what's wrong with second when expression - why it's
> evaluated to true when it should be false?

*The policy which you have made seems like correct , as the second value must be `false`,To do that we need to use `otherwise` and before `when`.*

Based on the [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#ChoosePolicyStatement):-

> *The control flow policy must contain at least one  element. The*
>  *element is optional. Conditions in  elements are*
> *evaluated in order of their appearance within the policy.  Policy
> statement(s) enclosed within the first  element with condition
> attribute* ***which is equals to `true` will be applied. Policies enclosed
> within the  element, if present, will be applied if all of
> the  element condition attributes are `false`*** .

For more information Please refer this **Blog**|[***Azure: Policies in API Management***](https://thecodeblogger.com/2019/03/11/azure-policies-in-api-management/) .